# How to retrieve the value of a cell in RasterLite?

Tags: raster, spatialite, sqlite, rasterlite

Just wanting to know the SQL statement needed to find out the pixel value for a location, when the raster is loaded into SpatialLite as a Raster?

I loaded the Raster using rasterlite_load -d db.sqlite -T myRaster -f c:\mytest.tif

All seems fine... but how would I find the value for a cell at say (100,400)?

Thanks
Phil